# Проблема с https на сайте

Tags: html, css, wordpress, https

Прошу помощи! Подключил ssl сертификат на сайт, появилась ошибка - подключение защищено не полностью, ругался на картинки, все ссылки переписал с htpp на https, изображения по новому загрузил и на главной странице стало все хорошо (https://3-3d.ru/), однако на остальных страницах сайта болячка осталась (для примера https://3-3d.ru/about-materials/) -  ""Mixed Content: The page at 'https://3-3d.ru/about-materials/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://3-3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Bg-Services-Hero-New.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://3-3d.ru/about-materials/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://3-3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/CTA-Shapes.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И что непонятно, так то что этих картинок в html коде попросту нет, и при переходе по ссылке расположения картинки - страница 404, опять же, потому что они удалены. Прошу сильно тапками не кидать - в этом деле новичок, заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызовы http идут из стилей elementor

https://3-3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-182.css

```
.elementor-background-overlay{background-image:url("http://3-3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/BG-contact-hero-New.png");

.elementor-background-overlay{background-image:url("http://3-3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/BG-contact-hero-New.png");
```

и т.д.

Для изменений зайти Админ - Elementor - Tools

Во вкладке есть "Replace Url" заменить ссылку на https

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вкладке "General" нажать "Regenerate CSS"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе Добрый Человек!